# User defined command

Tags: c

I am having a situation for which I am looking for some suggestion.

Suppose I write a program which prints the directory names of the directories.
Is it possible to convert this program into a command (just on my system).
Not be alias but via C only.

Comment: Hi @Bond ~ I would like to welcome you to StackOverflow and encourage you to read the FAQ (look up) and to visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask ~ Additionally, I'ld like to encourage you to either accept some answers or to update them with more information if the answers given didn't help you. We are, after all, a community driven site, and community begets community. Your contributions in asking quality questions helps us all grow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the file is *executable* (has the exec `x` access for the user starting it) and can be seen from the command interpreter (usually `bash` or `sh`), you can consider it to be a command.

There will be no difference in running your own file from your path than the `ls` command for instance.

Also, the C (or C++ ...) language is not a requirement. There are plenty of commands in, for instance, `/usr/bin` that are a *script*, meaning they're `sh` or `bash` (or even `perl`)...

- *access* Ensure the file has the `x` access right (e.g. `chmod u+x file`)
- *path* Ensure the file is in your PATH, or add an entry in your path (for instance) with `PATH=$PATH:mypath`
- *test* Test it well before to put it in a path from which other users may have access

Answer (score 1):

Put it in the path. On Linux, for example, you should put it in `/usr/local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

First, compile the program and create an executable using `gcc program.c -o myexecfile`. Then, an executable file named `myexecfile` is created in the same directory. You can run it by using `./myexecfile`.

If you are on Unix(Linux etc.) and want to use it like `ls` or any other standard command, you need to place it in a directory that is specified in $PATH variable. For example, `/usr/local/bin`.